# How can i create a shortcut to my website?

Tags: google-chrome, web, firefox, shortcut

As you know, Chrome and Mozilla for Android have an option to create a shortcut of a web page on the home screen. I was wondering if there is a way for me to add a button on my website and when the user presses it will create a shortcut to my website in the device's home menu or that I create that shortcut manually and can upload it to the cloud for user download. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should look into progressive web apps.

Comment: @Dharman Thanks, i'll check it